# New debug connectors for ARM

Tags: arm, jtag, swd, cortex

There is a big confusion in my head about debug connectors for ARM microprocessors. If I just take a look at [this documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.faqs/attached/13634/cortex_debug_connectors.pdf) there are a couple of JTAG connectors mentioned:

- **Cortex 10-pin JTAG/SWD (usualy 0.05" pitch)** which supports JTAG debug, SW debug, SW viewer

[image]

- **Cortex 20-pin JTAG/SWD/ETM (usualy 0.05" pitch)** supports JTAG debug, SW debug, SW viewer, trace operations.

[image]

- **Traditional 20-pin JTAG/SWD (usualy 0.10" pitch)** supports JTAG debug, SW debug

[image]

---

Now I could only find schematic on how to connect the **Traditional 20-pin JTAG/SWD** to the microcontroller and it is this one:

[image]

To completely understand the schematic I will paste power section as well. This is important, because it looks like entire circuit is powered by JTAG pin 19 which is connected to power regulator and then goes back to the JTAG connector pins 1, 2, 13...

[image]

Does anyone have any schematics for the other two?

Comment: the minimal you need for a cortex-m and often the only ones you need are swdio and swdclk.  And a ground and the debugger may wish to have a voltage reference to know say a 1.8 volt part from a 3.3v or other (know where to sample swdio and how high to drive swclk it may use your voltage ref possibly as vccio).  the other signals are for a universal arm jtag header and debugger that covers more members of the family jtag and swd.

Comment: Do you know if you are going to use JTAG or SWIO for debug? They are both debug/test ports, but some chips and IDEs offer different capabilities with them. The extra lines on the larger connectors (DBGRQ or Tracedata) provide extra, processor specific, debug access

Comment: I will use JTAG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the 10 pin one from my design using both SWD and JTAG

[image]

Couple of points:

1. VCC line is just to tell ST Link or other programmer the IO levels of debug interface.
2. KEY pin is optional. it has been taken care with connector type which do not allow wrong insertion It is not a signal, just a way to tell that there will be no pin on that position, so that we can also use low cost connector on board without pokayoke
3. Terminations - My design is for STM MCU, but it applies to all ARM MCUs in general. 
   [image]

One example for 20 pin. If trace pins are not sued, then they can be left open

[image]

> because it looks like entire circuit is powered by JTAG pin 19 which
>   is connected to power regulator and then goes back to the JTAG
>   connector pins 1, 2, 13...

DBGACK Pin - ”Debug Acknowledge” (high active) is an input of the debugger to sense the processors halt status. This is used in multi processor system and the pin itself may not be available on all MCUs.

Hence, please check **JTACVCC** source. JTAG connector is not supplying that for sure.